# Alternative to SharePoint Designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have come to the realization that SharePoint Designer 2010 is not as useful as its predecessor.  Are there any alternatives to SharePoint Designer 2010 that will allow me to do the same thing as SharePoint Designer 2007; modify a SharePoint site all the way down to the HTML and post it back to the SharePoint server so I can see the changes in real time?

Comment: What does SPD 2010 not do for you? For me, it does all of what you asked.

Comment: Agree, it is possible to edit the pages in the described fashion. Just edit the files in advanced mode by selecting it (right click)

Comment: As far as I know it still lets you edit the page. Can you be more precise on what specifically you can't do?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Designer 2010 is the tool of choice for editing live SharePoint 2010 sites.

Some features may be hard to find but most of them are there, and them some.

AFAIK there is no alternative.